# How to solve lowest eigenvalue with Lanczos or Arnoldi algorithm?

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithm, sparse-arrays

By setting `Method->Arnoldi` in `Eigensystem` I was able to solve lowest eigenvalue and eigenstate of a large sparse matrix. However, this requires writing out the large matrix explicitly. I am wondering if there is any more efficient way to use Arnoldi or Lanczos algorithm. For example, is it possible to solve lowest eigenvalue by just giving matrix basis and rules to produce matrix elements?

Comment: "rules to produce matrix elements" - and isn't that how your sparse array is specified?

Comment: If I understand your request correctly, then no this is currently not possible with `Eigensystem`. However to rule out a miss understanding it would be good if you can show some small example to look at. If it's truly not possible to do you should send this request to the support to be implemented in a future version.